# Codeigniter css not loading

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have a big problem with css and codeigniter.. I am starting to think it is my permissions or am I going mad?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/style.css" 
     type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css
```

This is my header file, and as you can see i've even echoed it out just to make sure it is right and it is, when I view source of the page it seems fine.. but somehow it is not doing anything, this is my css just to show you the background should be gray:

```
body{

background: #b6b6b6;
margin 0;
padding 0;
font-family: arial;
 }
```

my base url is fine.. as it is echoed out and goes to the right place
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/block/application';

I am really going mad what could be going wrong?

ht access:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: ..."deny from all" means no one, even you, can access it. And you do need another slash like what Paul and Musa say.

Comment: I have added another slash and it is in there right now, but it hasnt fixed the problem yet, should I change whats in my htaccess? as far as I know this what CI has supplied me with by default..

Comment: Ohhh. What is the folder that this htaccess file is in? And what is the folder your css is in? This htaccess prevents users from directly getting to a page. But all resource folders should have this: css, images, javascript, etc.

Comment: I have found out what it is :) my css folder was in the application bit, which CI seems to protect for its own good, I have moved it and changed the base url and everything is good now :) learned from my mistake!

Comment: If the base_url() is configured also try be removing base_url() from href and try directly for examle href="css/style.css" and href="js/js.css" etc without prefixing base_url()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `base_url()` to output the proper url, simply pass in the path as a parameter.

```
base_url('path/to/stylesheet.css');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, the page is forbidden though do you think it might be my permissions?

Comment: Barring a correct url, make sure permissions are at least 0644 (assuming linux/unix).

Comment: Permissions are 755

Have a look I have uploaded it.. : http://mintystudios.co.uk/ci/index.php/login

I still can't figure it out!

Comment: Please post your .htaccess in your original question.

Comment: done it right at the bottom, it just has this in it: "Deny from all"

Comment: Don't put deny from all, I commented on your question too.

Comment: Ah right that was you, sorry I am not very good with this website, but I have got it fixed by NEVER using application in your base url, because codeigniter protects this for its own good so people can't access core files!! makes sense, so don't put your css folder inside the application folder either for any future guests reading!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" 
type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css'); ?>" 
type="text/css" media="screen"/
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying so many things, what actually worked for me is to place the assets folder in the **root directory** **NOT** the **application directory**

Answer (score 0):

If your `base_url()` gives you `http://localhost/block/application` then the path to the css file will look like `http://localhost/block/applicationcss/style.css`, I think it should be `http://localhost/block/application/css/style.css`, so you're missing a `/`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/style.css" 
    type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: didnt work.. although the page is forbidden do you think it might be my permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `/` in your link `/css/style.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/style.css" 
 type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: didnt work.. although the page is forbidden do you think it might be my permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an htacess file with Deny From All in any resource folders.

You need to seperate out the css folder from the applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

you must take the css folder or file and put it in the root directory not the application directory
and use base_url function as i stated below

`<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>site.css"`